# how to control pose of an armature real time in blender?

Tags: python, armature

I'm creating a devise to identify hand movements and display on 3d hand model in blender.For that I used flex sensors and accelarometer to measure finger/hand movements.By using pyserial the sensor values are imported to bender as many variables.

I'm new to blender and python.I have created a hand model and need to run it using python script.I have added always sensor and python controller. I need to change the pose of the bone(actually euler angles) in real time using those sensor values(In blender game engine).

Answer (score 2):

There has been some work on using a kinect with blender, you might find some help in that work.

From python you can manipulate an armatures bones with -

```
myrigbones = bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones
myrigbones['chest'].rotation_euler = Euler((12.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

Don't think that will work in a game engine controller though - the [BL_ArmatureObject](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_6/bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.html) available in the game engine has a channels property to access bones.